# urlread2 not working with marketwatch

Tags: matlab, html-parsing, urlread

I have been using urlread2 to read financial statements from marketwatch, and it was previously working. I am trying to run the same Matlab script I previously ran and cannot get it work. The html variable returned is an empty matrix.

Any ideas ?

Here is a link to the function: https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/35693-urlread2
I know the function works, as I tried it running it on a different website.

Here is the Matlab script I am using.

```
url = ['http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/AAPL/financials/'];
url = strrep(url,' ','');
query  = 'urlread2';
params = {'term' query};
queryString = http_paramsToString(params,1);
url = [url '?' queryString];
[html,extras] = urlread2(url);
```

Comment: What is not working about it? Are you getting an error message or is there something else? What were you getting before when it was working?

Comment: I updated my original post. The html variable returned is an empty matrix.